# Azure Service Fabric: Restart an specific service/plugin only

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am looking for option to restart an specific service or plugin from service fabric explorer. Currenty for restarting a service I had to restart the node which should not be. I see option for deleting an specific service but not for restart.

**Is there any way to do this?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand "Nodes" and drill down to code package to restart individual "code" package.